# Как програмно определить лимит памяти при создании массива?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

Добрый день. При переносе Linux-приложения на платформу win32 (mingw32) возникла проблема резервирования памяти при создании массива максимально допустимого размера. Если в Linux без проблем работает такой код:

```
int V_V = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
std::unique_ptr<short[]> space{new short[V_V]};
```

то в win32 генерируется исключение. Я попытался програмно найти максимально допустимое значение для данной платформы:

```
try {
    std::unique_ptr<short[]> space{new short[V_V]};
    if (found = step_setup())
        cout << V_V << ": array created on " << &space[0] << endl;
} catch(std::exception & e) {
    show_err(e);
    V_V -= step;
}
```

и неожиданно выяснил, что допустимые предельные значения для создания массива не являются постоянной величиной:

```
f:\cDev\test_limit.exe

2147483647: std::bad_array_new_length
1047483647: std::bad_alloc
829153681: array created on 0x1dc2020

f:\cDev\test_limit.exe

2147483647: std::bad_array_new_length
1047483647: std::bad_alloc
828911645: array created on 0x1e30020
```

И могут меняться в 7м(!) разряде: от 828911645 до 829153681.

Существует ли программный API в стандартной библиотеке (без "windows.h") получить граничное значение размера для создаваемого массива?

Вот полный код теста:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <limits>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int V_V = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // creating array size
int step = 100000000; // step for search

bool step_setup()
{
    if(step > 1)
    {
        V_V += step;
        step = step / 10;
        return false;
    } else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Display only first error message
void show_err(std::exception & e)
{
    static std::string err{};
    if(err != e.what())
    {
        err = e.what();
        cout << V_V << ": " << err << endl;
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{ 
    cout << endl;
    bool found = false;
    while (!found)
    {
        try {
        std::unique_ptr<short[]> space{new short[V_V]};
        if (found = step_setup())
            cout << V_V << ": array created on "
                 << &space[0] << endl;
        } catch(std::exception & e) {
            show_err(e);
            V_V -= step;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `MEMORYSTATUSEX statex; statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex); GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);` `ullAvailPageFile` - макс размер массива, если не резервировать, `ullAvailVirtual`. Можно полный код, что-то не понял, адрес выделенного нового байта оно показывает?)

Comment: добавил полный код в конце сообщения.

Comment: Вы в Linux пробовали работать со всей этой памятью? Записать что-то в каждый байт? Поскольку давать ссылку как ответ считается не комильфо, дам комментарий: почитайте задачу 23 из "Новые сложные задачи на C++" Саттера, там есть на эту тему. Как понимаю ситуацию - тут командует операционная система, которая сама определяет, какие ресурсы вам доступны *в текущий момент*. Стоит измениться окружению - что-то заработало в фоне, программа запущена не с того же физического адреса - и начинаются отличия. В выделение одним куском 4Г памяти в Linux верится тоже слабо - или вы что-то не договариваете :)

Comment: @Harry сам проверил, выделяет 25 гиг и пишет=, я прерывал т.к тормозит надо бы дальше проверить). Здесь неправильное нахождение, написал бы свою только в коммент недобно. В windows 8 размер = `3 * .ullTotalPhys - .ullTotalPageFile + .ullAvailPageFile`, резервировать можно больше, только я в этом не разбираюсь, зачем если не получится использовать

Comment: В Linux память, без каких-либо менеджеров, вначале автоматически резервируется, не переходя полностью приложению. Что-то типа встроенного VirtualAlloc из wihdows.h. Тестовая программа на базе OpenGL во время работы занимает всего 700 килобайт с уже инициализированным предельным значением массивом. Кстати, это-же приложение в Win32 уже использует 3,8 мегабайта. Подробнее пока не могу рассказать, так как сам еще не до конца разобрался.

Comment: @J.Doe 25Г - никак 32 битами не адресовать...

Comment: @bigov Вот, про то и у Саттера написано в той 23 задаче, что я упоминал. Что возврат указателя еще не есть реальная выделенная память.

Comment: так я вобще-то и не заморачивался "выделено" или "зарезервировано". В том-же коде в конце поста можно дописать проверку в блоке try:

    ....
        << &space[0] << endl;
    space[0] = 88;
    space[V_V] = 11;
    int m; std::cin >> m;
    cout << m << ", " << space[0] << ", " << space[V_V] << endl;
    } catch ...

и увидеть, что приложение заняло 500 килобайт, но массив работает. Вопрос в топике в том, СКОЛЬКО можно запросить МУЛЬТИПЛАТФОРМЕННО. Без windows.h.

Comment: @J.Doe - я тоже как то не понял, как это Вы 25Г адресовали?

Comment: @bigov Вы запрашиваете память у операционной системы, интересуетесь характеристикой операционной системы, - и хотите получить это без участия системы? Утрируя - а если вы скомпилируете программу под DOS, сколько получите? :) Словом, я бы ни в коем случае не стал полагаться на возможность выделения некоторого максимума. Если он будет выделен, но без коммита, грубо говоря - велик шанс нарваться на *неопознанную* проблему при работе - нарушение доступа. Если с коммитом - то шанс нарваться на постоянный своп или проблемы других программ. Я бы просил памяти столько, сколько мне надо, не жадничая :)

Comment: @Harry Вы абсолютно правы. Использовать в программе предельные значения физических ресурсов - глупость. Но для пректирования эффективного алгоритма надо хотя-бы иметь  представление об их границах. Тогда понятно будет, как реализовать задачу.

Например, можно-ли тот-же пресловутый массив "space" использовать "в лоб" или потребуется строить обертку для его сегментирования.

Comment: Да, насчет системы. Все свидетельствует о том, что без использования API конкретной платформы ничего мультиплатформенного качественно не получится. Простите за каламбур.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке С++ нет програмного API для прямого определения размера выделяемой памяти. Но можно немого изменить клиентский код и воспользоваться стандартным контейнером, что кстати и рекомендуется в С++. А далее уже запросить значение предельного размера созданного контейнера. Например:

```
// comparing size, capacity and max_size
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;

    // set some content in the vector:
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

    std::cout << "size: " << myvector.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "capacity: " << myvector.capacity() << "\n";
    std::cout << "max_size: " << myvector.max_size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
size: 100
capacity: 128
max_size: 1073741823
```

Comment: max_size это просто максимальный теоретичекий размер контейнера. "1073741823*4 == 0xFFFFFFFC" - то есть, без 4 байт 4 гигабайта. Я могу гарантировать, что на 90% 32 битных систем выделить более 2 гигов очень и очень накладно, не говоря уже о 4.  Так что Ваш код абсолютно не решает поставленную в вопросе задачу.

Comment: Хочу заметить, что на 32 битной системе результат "max_size" будет другим - он будет соответствовать возможности теущей системы.  А в вопросе требуется именно "получить граничное значение размера". Так что мой ответ решает поставленную задачу.

Comment: Указанный выше результат это как раз для 32битной системы (если быть ещё точнее, то для 32битного бинарника). И Вы не поверите, на всех 32битных системах, где я пробовал этот код, он выводит одно и тоже. Более того, если 32битный бинарник запустить на 64 битной системе, результат будет тот же.